# Javascript: add <br> if find special character

Tags: javascript

My javascript code return this string: `Al Kawkab - Al-Ain`.
I would like, the javascript code add to enter after the dash so that the text starts with a new line.

I would like to achieve such a result:

`Al Kawkab -
Al-Ain`

```
$($('.title a').children().prevObject).each(function (index) {
                console.log(index + ": " + $( this ).text() );

                if ($( this ).text().length > 34) {

                          // add <br> after dash

                }

            });
```

Comment: @B001 I added in post

Comment: Hint : use `.replace( .... )` to replace "dash" with "dash and a line break".

Comment: your code is performing actions on some html,you should post that aswell

Comment: `str.replace(/\s([-_*])\s/g," $1<br/>")`

Comment: @Kashan I would like to use only jQuery, if it is possible

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54105642/edit) and then make a snippet `[<>]`  with a [mcve]

Comment: @Kashan I don't think HTML code is relevant here. We know that the text is `Al Kawkab - Al-Ain`, knowing that it comes from an `<input />` won't help much more

Comment: @JeremyThille this is a text in <a href=''> tag

Comment: Yes, as I said, you're interested in manipulating a text; where it came from doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    var stext = $( this ).text();
    if (sText.length > 34) {
       var indexOf = $( this ).text().indexOf(' - ');
       if(indexOf > -1){
          var aTextSplit = sText.split(" - ");
          var sNewText = aTextSplit[0];
          for(var i=1; i<aTextSplit.length; i++){
             sNewText = sNewText + " -" + "\n" + aTextSplit[i];
          }
          $( this ).text(sNewText);
       }
   }
```

/n will add a break line to your code... If this doesnt works then change /n to

I used the inner for loop in case there are more than 1 " - ".
If there is only " - ". Then you can avoid for loop as shown below:

```
    var stext = $( this ).text();
    if (sText.length > 34) {
       var indexOf = $( this ).text().indexOf(' - ');
       if(indexOf > -1){
          var aTextSplit = sText.split(" - ");
          var sNewText = aTextSplit[0] + " -" + "\n" aTextSplit[1];
          $( this ).text(sNewText);
       }
   }
```